# WCF deserialization issue (json)

Tags: c#, json, wcf, service

I built a WCF service that could get requests from different clients using json.
One client could send:

```
"actor": {"name":["Joe User"],"mbox":["mailto:user@example.com"]}
```

another one:

```
"actor": {"name": "Joe User", "mbox": "mailto:user@example.com"}
```

So, one could send a list for 'name' and another just a string. My **DataContract** object handles 'name' as a string. The problem is that the WCF service throws an error if 'name' is actually a list. Is it possible to somehow handle arrays also?

Comment: No way you can change the schema?  It's not a very good idea to have two classes called `actor` where one uses strings and another uses arrays.  Could you rename the top one `actors`?  Or, better yet, `"actors": [{ "name": "Joe User", "mbox": "mailto:user@example.com"}]` so you're not using two arrays that are ordinal dependent?

Comment: You can change the name to an anonymous object, and convert it to an array at all times.

Comment: I don't have any control over that but I would like to support both formats.